# Paypal sdk with laravel - getting Client_id/secret from env file

Tags: laravel, paypal, payment-gateway

I added my paypal secret and client id into the .env  like so

**.env**

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:B/bzbrXZMyRkg//1Do63pacV/pKHtTIYKd42/zq3n6c=

Client_Id='ID GOES HERE'
Client_Secret='SECRET KEY GOES HERE'
```

I want to access those in my controller

**PaypalPaymentController**

```
class PaypalPaymentController extends Controller {

    private $_api_context;
    private $_ClientId =    env('Client_Id');
    private $_ClientSecret =    env('Client_Secret');

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_api_context = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential($this->_ClientId, $this->_ClientSecret));
    }
public function handle(Request $request) {
  //  dd(env('Client_Id')); // when i do this it dumps the Client_id
}
```

But this throws an **Error**

> FatalErrorException in PaypalPaymentController.php line 41:
>
> Constant expression contains invalid operations

Can any one explain to me why it dosent work? and how can i fix it!

**Note**: I can manage to make this work by adding the client_id and secret directly into the controller but i think using env is a better way (best practices) , correct me if im wrong!
!!

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but for good practice sake, constants should be all uppercase

Comment: thank you for that :3 good practices advise is always appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make this work like this

```
 class PaypalPaymentController extends Controller {

    private $_api_context;

    public function __construct() {

        $_ClientId = env('Client_Id');
        $_ClientSecret = env('Client_Secret');

        $this->_api_context = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential($_ClientId, $_ClientSecret));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your env file, the value should not have any single or double quotes.